# How to convert the following java android code into the swift language for iOS for writing current time characteristics for BLE device

Tags: android, ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an android code to write current time data to the peripheral(Omron BP7000) and I am trying to convert it to swift language but I am unable to do so because I am getting an error : `NSError domain: "CBATTErrorDomain" - code: 128  0x0000000282b111a0.`

Following is the andriod code :

```
 public void setCurrentTime(@NotNull final Calendar calendar) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(calendar);

        mValue = new byte[10];
        mValue[0] = (byte) calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mValue[1] = (byte) (calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) >> 8);
        mValue[2] = (byte) (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
        mValue[3] = (byte) calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
        mValue[4] = (byte) calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mValue[5] = (byte) calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        mValue[6] = (byte) calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        mValue[7] = (byte) ((calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 5) % 7 + 1);
        mValue[8] = (byte) (calendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) * 256 / 1000);
        mValue[9] = 1;
    }
```

I have tried to convert it to iOS swift and gotten following code:

```
      var mValue = Data(count: 10)

      let calendar = Calendar.current
      let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second, .weekday, .nanosecond], from: currentDate)

        mValue[0] = UInt8(components.year! & 0x119)
        mValue[1] = UInt8(components.year! >> 8)
        mValue[2] = UInt8(components.month! )
        mValue[3] = UInt8(components.day!)
        mValue[4] = UInt8(components.hour!)
        mValue[5] = UInt8(components.minute!)
        mValue[6] = UInt8(components.second!)
        mValue[7] = components.btDayOfWeek
        mValue[8] = UInt8(components.nanosecond! * 256 / Int(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        mValue[9] = 1
        peripheral.writeValue(mValue, for: characteristic, type: .withResponse)
```

even with converted code I am not getting the success when I am writing the time. Any help in correcting my swift iOS code will be helpful. I tried to get the hardcoded values from the android code they are as following -

android output:-

```
[-25, 7, 6, 28, 13, 59, 46, 3, 88, 1]
```

and  swift output for the above code is ADDED AS AN IMAGE. - and here

```
[ 31 , 7 , 6, 28 ,15, 46 , 53 , 3 ,71 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,  0 , 0 ]
```

Comment: I don't understand how you got "0,0,0,0". Also, what's the year logic exactly? How did you print the number array in Swift?

Comment: The year in android is divided into two parts and I tried to replicate the same in swift iOS. in android the byte is ranging from -128 to 127 and in swift it is 0 to 255. And the output part  with 0,0,0,0 I am getting it console in debug area(bottom left in Xcode), there are total of 14 index. I tried to upload image of it but it is not getting on the question I posted

Comment: @Kshitij876 please [edit] your question to add the code where you print mValue

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan Hello, Done with the edit

Comment: @Kshitij876 so the output you shows us is what the peripheral received? What is the characteristic length you are writing to?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan the length expected to the peripheral device is 10 bytes. And the output part in swift I can just pull my cursor to the mValue and get the values and indexes i.e print the mValue, I tried to put the screenshot of the image as well of my console but it is not showing in the edit.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with swift and therefore can't tell you why your data object of size 10 shows as a size 14 when debugging. But I believe you're setting the first value incorrectly in mValue[0]. You use a bitwise AND (`&`) to only receive the first 8 bit of the number. But you do it with a hex value of `0x119` which is `000100011001` but you want to use `0xF` which is `00001111`